# Conditional CSS class fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, clsx

I have many pages, and the home page, if i am in the homepage, i want to make the bg transparent, if the shrink menu is true make it solid (bg-[color:rgb(var(--color-header-bg))]), if i am in other pages make the bg bg-[color:rgb(var(--color-header-bg))] no matter what

```
  <div
          className={clsx(
            shrinkMenu ? 'lg:min-h-header-sm' : 'lg:min-h-header-lg',
            isHome
              ? 'border-white/40 bg-transparent'
              : 'border-dark/20 bg-[color:rgb(var(--color-header-bg))]',
            isHome && shrinkMenu
              ? 'bg-[color:rgb(var(--color-header-bg))]'
              : 'bg-transparent',
          )}
        >
```

The issue is in homepage, bg-transparent persists even shrinkmenu is true, how can I improve this code?

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable demo, such as `codesandbox` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to have your conditions in a different order:

```html
<div
  className={clsx(
    isHome && shrinkMenu
      ? 'lg:min-h-header-sm bg-[color:rgb(var(--color-header-bg))]'
      : isHome
      ? 'lg:min-h-header-sm bg-transparent'
      : 'lg:min-h-header-lg bg-[color:rgb(var(--color-header-bg))]'
  )}
>
```

CSS classes that are applied to an element are processed from left to right and the last class that's applied takes precedence. In your code the condition for `isHome` and `shrinkMenu` to both be true came after the condition for `isHome` alone. Therefore the `bg-transparent` class was applied last (after the `bg-[color:rgb(var(--color-header-bg))]` class) and took precedence, making the background transparent even when `shrinkMenu` is true.

Comment: it's working, but the height is not changing this time